# Scaling issue with d3.js library

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am using this library - https://github.com/ofrohn/d3-celestial
But I want to retain the width and height on PC, and do a CSS `transform: scale()` on the elements to fit on mobile. The problem is, the projection tries to fit into mobile and grows so big if I set the `width` option to custom.

[image]

Leaving it to 0 makes it too small

[image]

. Other elements scales.

On PC, it just fits:

[image]

I had tried setting `interactive=false` and it doesn't work. I just want to scale everything in the container and retain it sizes.

The code is below, I would like to keep the globe in place, text beneath it in same position and maintain same ratio both on mobile and P

```js
var config = {
  width: 0,
  projection: "airy",
  projectionRatio: null,
  transform: "equatorial",
  center: null,
  orientationfixed: true,
  background: {
    fill: "#000000",
    stroke: "#000000",
    opacity: 1
  },
  adaptable: true,
  interactive: true,
  disableAnimations: false,
  form: false,
  location: false,
  controls: false,
  lang: "",
  container: "starmap",
  datapath: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-celestial@0.7.35/data/",
  stars: {
    show: true,
    limit: 6,
    colors: false,
    style: {
      fill: "#ffffff",
      opacity: 1
    },
    names: false,
    proper: false,
    desig: false,
    namelimit: 2.5,
    namestyle: {
      fill: "#ddddbb",
      font: "11px Georgia, Times, 'Times Roman', serif",
      align: "left",
      baseline: "top"
    },
    propernamestyle: {
      fill: "#ddddbb",
      font: "11px Georgia, Times, 'Times Roman', serif",
      align: "right",
      baseline: "bottom"
    },
    propernamelimit: 1.5,
    size: 6,
    exponent: -0.28,
    data: 'stars.6.json'
  },
  dsos: {
    show: false, // Show Deep Space Objects
    limit: 6, // Show only DSOs brighter than limit magnitude
    names: false, // Show DSO names
    desig: false, // Show short DSO names
    namelimit: 4, // Show only names for DSOs brighter than namelimit
    namestyle: {
      fill: "#cccccc",
      font: "11px Helvetica, Arial, serif",
      align: "left",
      baseline: "top"
    },
    size: null, // Optional seperate scale size for DSOs, null = stars.size
    exponent: 1.4, // Scale exponent for DSO size, larger = more non-linear
    data: 'dsos.bright.json', // Data source for DSOs
    //data: 'dsos.6.json'  // Alternative broader data source for DSOs
    //data: 'dsos.14.json' // Alternative deeper data source for DSOs
    symbols: { //DSO symbol styles
      gg: {
        shape: "circle",
        fill: "#ff0000"
      }, // Galaxy cluster
      g: {
        shape: "ellipse",
        fill: "#ff0000"
      }, // Generic galaxy
      s: {
        shape: "ellipse",
        fill: "#ff0000"
      }, // Spiral galaxy
      s0: {
        shape: "ellipse",
        fill: "#ff0000"
      }, // Lenticular galaxy
      sd: {
        shape: "ellipse",
        fill: "#ff0000"
      }, // Dwarf galaxy
      e: {
        shape: "ellipse",
        fill: "#ff0000"
      }, // Elliptical galaxy
      i: {
        shape: "ellipse",
        fill: "#ff0000"
      }, // Irregular galaxy
      oc: {
        shape: "circle",
        fill: "#ffcc00",
        stroke: "#ffcc00",
        width: 1.5
      }, // Open cluster
      gc: {
        shape: "circle",
        fill: "#ff9900"
      }, // Globular cluster
      en: {
        shape: "square",
        fill: "#ff00cc"
      }, // Emission nebula
      bn: {
        shape: "square",
        fill: "#ff00cc",
        stroke: "#ff00cc",
        width: 2
      }, // Generic bright nebula
      sfr: {
        shape: "square",
        fill: "#cc00ff",
        stroke: "#cc00ff",
        width: 2
      }, // Star forming region
      rn: {
        shape: "square",
        fill: "#00ooff"
      }, // Reflection nebula
      pn: {
        shape: "diamond",
        fill: "#00cccc"
      }, // Planetary nebula
      snr: {
        shape: "diamond",
        fill: "#ff00cc"
      }, // Supernova remnant
      dn: {
        shape: "square",
        fill: "#999999",
        stroke: "#999999",
        width: 2
      }, // Dark nebula grey
      pos: {
        shape: "marker",
        fill: "#cccccc",
        stroke: "#cccccc",
        width: 1.5
      } // Generic marker
    }
  },
  constellations: {
    show: false, // Show constellations
    names: false, // Show constellation names
    desig: false, // Show short constellation names (3 letter designations)
    namestyle: {
      fill: "#cccc99",
      align: "center",
      baseline: "middle",
      opacity: 0.8,
      font: ["bold 14px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif", // Different fonts for brighter &
        "bold 12px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif", // sdarker constellations
        "bold 11px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif"
      ]
    },
    lines: true, // Show constellation lines
    linestyle: {
      stroke: "#cccccc",
      width: 1,
      opacity: 0.6
    },
    bounds: false, // Show constellation boundaries
    boundstyle: {
      stroke: "#cccc00",
      width: 0.5,
      opacity: 0.8,
      dash: [2, 4]
    }
  },
  mw: {
    show: true, // Show Milky Way as filled polygons
    style: {
      fill: "#ffffff",
      opacity: "0.15"
    }
  },
  lines: {
    graticule: {
      show: true,
      stroke: "#cccccc",
      width: 0.6,
      opacity: 0.8, // Show graticule lines
      // grid values: "outline", "center", or [lat,...] specific position
      lon: {
        pos: ["center"],
        fill: "#eee",
        font: "10px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif"
      },
      // grid values: "outline", "center", or [lon,...] specific position
      lat: {
        pos: ["center"],
        fill: "#eee",
        font: "10px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif"
      }
    },
    equatorial: {
      show: false,
      stroke: "#aaaaaa",
      width: 1.3,
      opacity: 0.7
    }, // Show equatorial plane
    ecliptic: {
      show: false,
      stroke: "#66cc66",
      width: 1.3,
      opacity: 0.7
    }, // Show ecliptic plane
    galactic: {
      show: false,
      stroke: "#cc6666",
      width: 1.3,
      opacity: 0.7
    }, // Show galactic plane
    supergalactic: {
      show: false,
      stroke: "#cc66cc",
      width: 1.3,
      opacity: 0.7
    } // Show supergalactic plane
  }
};

Celestial.display(config);
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.paper {
  width: 17.4cm;
  height: 23.78cm;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px #ccc;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

#starmap {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.extra-text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-celestial@0.7.35/lib/d3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-celestial@0.7.35/lib/d3.geo.projection.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-celestial@0.7.35/celestial.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-celestial@0.7.35/celestial.css" />

<div class="paper">
  <div id="starmap"></div>
  <div class="extra-text">Foo bar</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add your code, a runnable snippet containing a [mre]. It will help you get better answers

Comment: You set the width of the container `#paper` to 17cm... Removing that fixes the issue

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be fixed by giving the `height` and `width` to `canvas`
e.g.

```
canvas {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}
```